# angular 2 component with ngrx - errors when run unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx

I'm working on angular 2 project, using ngrx (for Redux logic) and rxjs (for observable).

Now I try to testing the project by running the auto-created .spec.ts files.

Some of the testings are fail, all of them are testing of components which use Store (from ngrx). 
Here is one of them:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { MyComponent } from './overlay-menu-item.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

I look after the problem, the error was:

> No provider to Store

So I add: (I use jasmine for testing)

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  providers: [Store]
 })
 .compileComponents();
}));
```

Now I got other error:

> No provider for StateObservable

So I add:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  providers: [Store, StateObservable]
 })
 .compileComponents();
}));
```

**But now I got new error that I don't know what do to with it:**

> ```
> Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for StateObservable: (?).
>     Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StateObservable: (?).
>         at syntaxError [mywebprojectPath]/node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1689:22)
> ```

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 4):

You should create a [MockStore](https://blog.realworldfullstack.io/real-world-angular-part-9-unit-testing-c62ba20b1d93).

In short:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';

export class MockStore<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {  
  constructor(private _initialState: T) {
    super(_initialState);
  }
  dispatch = (action: Action): void => {
  }

  select = <T, R>(pathOrMapFn: any, ...paths: string[]): Observable<R> => {
    return map.call(this, pathOrMapFn);
  }
}
```

Then you can provide the mockStore in you tests:

```
const initialState = {...};
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers:[
    {provide:Store, useValue: new MockStore(initialState)}
  ]
  ...
})
```

Comment: @user5260143 I had the same challenge and this answer provided the solution. I think it should be accepted.

Comment: This is indeed the solution to this type of problem. Thumbs up!